# Messages not appearing on message subfile on bottom of screen

Tags: rpgle

I have written a basic maintenance function in RPGLE, using DDS to create the display file.  I have a message subfile defined to show the message on line 24.  The message subfile control record has an overlay defined.  The messages are being written to the pgm (checked the job logs and can see the correct messages being sent to the correct program).  SFLPGMQ is defined as '*' (I also tried putting the full pgm name in as well - same thing).  The whole program is written entirely in fully free-format RPG.   I have the following formats:
HEADER  (No overlay defined) - This contains narrative on the first 4 lines.
SUBFILE  (Control record has overlay defined) - Subfile lines 6-21
FUNCKEYS (Display the set of allowed function keys on row 23 - Overlay defined)
MSGSFL  (Control record has overlay defined) - SFLMSGRCD(24)

When building the screen:
Write Header
Write Funckeys
Write MsgSflC
Exfmt SUBFILEC

The odd thing is - I have a very similar sort of subfile that uses a window.  My method is virtually identical to this program - but that works fine!

I have been pulling my hair out for a few hours now and cannot for the life of me understand what is going on!!!!   Please please someone put me out of my misery!

This is the DDS for the display file

```
A                                      DSPSIZ(24 80 *DS3)             
A                                      INDARA                         
A                                      CF03(03)                       
A                                      CF06(06)                       
A                                      CF12(12)                       

 ** Header                                                            
A          R HEADER                                                   
A                                  1  2'XXXXXXS1'                     
A                                  1 28'Maintain XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  
A                                      DSPATR(HI)                     
A                                  1 63DATE                           
A                                      EDTCDE(Y)                      
A                                  1 72TIME                           
A                                  3  2'2=Edit   4=Delete'   
A                                      COLOR(BLU)                     

 ** Subfile                                                         
A          R SUBFILE                   SFL                          
A  94                                  SFLNXTCHG                    
A            S_OPT          1A  B  6  3                             
A  51                                  DSPATR(RI PC)                                     
A            S_TRANTYPE    30A  O  6  8                             
A            S_RRN          5S 0H                                   

 ** Subfile control                                                 
A          R SUBFILEC                  SFLCTL(SUBFILE)              
A                                      OVERLAY                      
A  91                                  SFLDSP                       
A  92                                  SFLDSPCTL                    
A  90                                  SFLCLR                       
A  93                                  SFLEND(*MORE)                
A                                      SFLSIZ(17)                   
A                                      SFLPAG(16)                   
A                                  5  2'Opt' 
A                                      DSPATR(HI)                        
A                                  5  8'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'                
A                                      DSPATR(HI)                        

 ** Function keys                                                        
A          R FUNCKEYS                                                    
A                                      OVERLAY                           
A                                 23  2'F3=Exit   F6=Add   F12=Cancel'   
A                                      COLOR(BLU)                        

 ** No xxxxxxxx available                                       
A          R NOTRANS                                                     
A                                      OVERLAY                           
A                                 10 10'*** There are no XXXXXXX defined ***'               
A                                       DSPATR(HI)                       

 ** Messages                                                             
A          R MSGSFL                    SFL                               
A                                      SFLMSGRCD(24)                     
A            MSGKEY                    SFLMSGKEY                            
A            PGMQ                      SFLPGMQ                              

A          R MSGCTL                    SFLCTL(MSGSFL)                       
A                                      OVERLAY                              
A                                      SFLDSP                               
A                                      SFLDSPCTL                            
A                                      SFLINZ                               
A N12                                  SFLEND                               
A                                      SFLSIZ(2)                            
A                                      SFLPAG(1)                            
A            PGMQ                      SFLPGMQ(10)
```

Below is the essence of the building of the screen.  The screen displays everything correctly - except no messages at the bottom!

PGMQ is set to '*' at the start of the program

```
dcl-proc DisplayScreen;                                   

    write HEADER;                                         
    write FUNCKEYS;                                       
    write MSGCTL;                                      
    if S_RRN <> *zero;                                    
       SflDspCtl = *on;                                   
       SflDsp = *on;                                      
       exfmt SUBFILEC;                                     
    else;                                                 
       exfmt NOTRANS;                                     
    endif;                                                

end-proc;
```

Only 1 record can be selected at a time.  If more than one, a message should be displayed at the bottom - along with all the relevant records highlighted on field S_OPT.  The highlighting of all fields works fine - and the message appears in the job log!  SO I would expect them to appear in the MSGSFL!  I'm sure i'm doing something stupid - but cannot for the life of me see what!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious problems with the code you've posted, so I suspect the issue is somewhere else in your mainline or edit routine that you didn't post the code for. My suspicion is that you're clearing the program message queue somewhere between writing the error messages and returning back to DisplayScreen process, so the messages never make it to the subfile.

--Rob

Answer (score 0):

This looks just like what I use, with one exception. I put the program name (from the PSDS) into the program queue. Then when sending messages, I send them explicitly to the same queue. That way I know that they are all pointing to the same thing. You have not shown the routine that sends the message, but you need to make sure that you are not sending to something "down the chain" that is you need to send to the stack entry named with counter 0. I also only clear the message queue immediately after a read of the display file.

Here's the procedure I use to send messages to a display file:

```
// ------------------------------------
// Send Message to Display File (MSGID)
// Sends a message to the display file message subfile
//
// Parameters:
//  pgmq        - Program message queue. This must be the same as the pgmq
//                specified in the display file.
//  messageId   - The message id of the message to be sent
//  messageData - Message data for replacement values in the message. Format
//                of the message data is defined by the message. This is
//                optional, if missing, blanks are used.
//  messageFile - The qualified name of the message file containing the
//                message. The first 10 characters is the messafe file name,
//                the second 10 characters is the library. This is optional,
//                if blank, QCPFMSG in *LIBL is used.
// ------------------------------------
dcl-proc SendDspfMsg Export;
  dcl-pi *n;
    pgmq           Char(10) const;
    messageId      Char(7) const;
    messageData    Varchar(256) const options(*varsize: *nopass);
    messageFile    LikeDs(qualName_t) const options(*nopass);
  end-pi;

  dcl-ds msgf      LikeDs(qualName_t) Inz(*likeds);
  dcl-ds ec        LikeDs(errCode_t) Inz(*likeds);

  dcl-s msgData    Char(256) Inz('');

  if %parms() >= %parmnum(messageData);
    msgData = messageData;
  endif;
  if %parms() >= %parmnum(messageFile);
    msgf = messageFile;
  else;
    msgf.name = 'QCPFMSG';
  endif;

  qmhsndpm(messageId: msgf: msgData: %size(msgData): '*INFO': pgmq: 0: '': ec);
end-proc;
```

Comment: Have tried the Psds approach also. I will try and find time to post the while code in the next few days. Appreciate all your efforts - I’m a seasoned iSeries professional  of 20+ years . Written many pgms  with message subfiles- but had a 2 year break until recently! Don’t know if something drastic has changed in that time - but I can’t work it out!

Comment: No changes. My experience when this kind of thing fails is that the display file and the send message are not pointing at the same message queue. either because the queue specified is different, or because the counter is wrong.

Comment: I see you are using procedures. There is a difference between how procedures and subroutines use the call stack. procedures are on the call stack, but subroutines are not. This could cause `CALL QCMDEXC` operate differently, and unexpectedly. That is why I always use the API call `QMHSNDPM` rather than the command `SNDPGMMSG` when I am using procedures. Not sure which way you are sending the messages, but my procedure above will work much nicer in a procedure environment.

Comment: I’m using a call to a Service program that does SNDPGMMSG.  Will try the QMHSNDPM option and see how that works.  (On holiday this week so will wait till next Monday )

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do.....note the weird 12 or not 12 for the SFLEND keyword.
I was told to use that 20 years ago and always have done since....can't remember the reason though!

I also move asterisk in to PGMQ as below as the first line of my RPG

DDS:

```
A          R MSGSFL                    SFL             
A                                      SFLMSGRCD(24)   
A            MSGKEY                    SFLMSGKEY       
A            PGMQ                      SFLPGMQ         
A          R MSGCTL                    SFLCTL(MSGSFL)    
A                                      OVERLAY         
A                                      SFLINZ          
A                                      SFLSIZ(2)       
A                                      SFLPAG(1)       
A  12                                                  
AON12                                  SFLEND          
A                                      SFLDSP SFLDSPCTL
A            PGMQ                      SFLPGMQ
```

RPG:

```
C                   movel(p)  '*'           pgmq
```

Comment: The reason for the `12 or not 12` for the SFLEND keyword is that you have to have something there, and if you just use `12`, or `N12` without the other, you must make sure indicator 12 is set to make that condition true for the `+` to disappear on the last row of the subfile. `12 or N12` is always true. It could actually be any indicator, and you don't even have to reserve it for this purpose, but I usually use the same indicator all the time, just so I know what it is.